# OraOLEDB.Oracle not showing in SQL Server Management Studio providers

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oledb, linked-server

I'm trying to add an Oracle server as a linked server to SQL Server. I've downloaded and installed Oracle's instant client and ODAC software. However, OraOLEDB.Oracle does not show up in the list of providers in SSMS. My machine is running Windows 7 (64 bit) and MSSQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Have tried installing both x86 and x64 clients for Oracle. Not sure, but will keep this window up and post if I find the solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue now. Did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to fix this same issue. I found this detailed set of instructions, however they didn't work for me. I encountered some installation errors with ODAC. Perhaps they can be of help to you though.

**Installing 64-bit Oracle ODAC 11.2 to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 x64**
http://nampark.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/installing-64-bit-odac-11-2-to-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2-x64-for-replication/

Answer (score 1):

OraOLEDB provider is not installed with instant client. You have to install the full client.